# Reputation question

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit

Empirically, I see that it is impossible to get more than around 270 points in a day (the system stops giving credit after a while). And yet, when you look at the list of top weekly rep gatherers, it looks like number 1 has gotten around 500 points a day. How is this possible?

Comment: Empirically I know that it’s possible to get $500$ without bounties, having done it on $4$ and $7$ November $2012$. It just needs a *lot* of acceptances.

Answer (score 10):

You can get at most 200 points in a day from upvotes. But bounties and +15 bonus for accepted answers are exempt from the cap. Hence, the total number of points one can get in a day is not limited.

For details, see [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237)

Comment: @Igor: Sorry, the level of your security clearance is not high enough. If I told you, I'd have to kill you...

Comment: @AsafKaragil In that case I won't tell you who invented the vacation...

Comment: @Igor: That was No. Six, and that is why he was taken to The Village.

Comment: @AsafKaragila interesting theory, but incorrect. Everything you know, is wrong: http://youtu.be/EtXGKqWz8nU

Comment: @IgorRivin: Indians can be in two places at once!

Comment: @Thomas: Bounties appear to be mentioned in the second sentence.

Comment: @robjohn: I should probably go get a degree in "reading things carefully".

Comment: @Igor: I was expecting something else when you said that everything I know is wrong: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qits3nn73ks